# How to add rows between current end_time and next row start_time in PySpark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, overlap

I am making a PySpark script to delete overlap in the start_time and end_time columns. When there is overlap verrekenbaar has priority. So if you have these 2 rows the first rows end_time will go from '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z' to '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z':

```
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-26T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z'), 
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z')
```

**Result:**

```
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z')
```

This logic I already have. So now the real question.......

When there is a row with niet-verrekenbaar and there are multiple rows of verrekenbaar that fall within the time range of this row. It needs to add rows, because rows with verrekenbaar sort of cut the time range in smaller pieces of the bigger row with niet-verrekenbaar.

**Here is an example :**

```
> data1 = [
    (123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-13T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-25T00:00:00.000Z'),
    (123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-16T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-17T00:00:00.000Z'),
    (123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-19T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-20T00:00:00.000Z'),
    (123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'),
    (123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-26T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z'),
    (123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z')
]
```

So This needs to be the outcome, so row 3 and 5 are added:

```
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-13T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-16T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-16T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-17T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-17T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-19T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-19T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-20T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-20T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'niet-verrekenbaar', '2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z'),
(123, 202009, 1, 'verrekenbaar', '2020-09-29T00:00:00.000Z', '2020-09-31T00:00:00.000Z')
```

The script needs to be written in Pyspark or SQL.

Maybe this can help aswell to clarify it more, so you go from 3 rows to 5 with this picture example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use lead() method on pyspark
Logic is like:

1. Create a new column with lead method called '*lead_column*', it will give you next available date
2. If *lead_column* and *end_date* have diff, then create new column with *end_date* as *start_date_new* and *lead_column* as *end_date_new* (this is used to add missing dates in data)
3. If no difference between *lead_column* and *end_date*, then update *end_date* with *lead_column*
4. if there is difference, then create new entry for *start_date_new* and *end_date_new* and append it to updated dataframe

Hope this will work